# I need to read the xlsx file in java

Tags: java, xlsx

But am receiving errors. is there any error in it.
     File myFile = new File("D:/abhilash/L2t Tracker.xlsx");
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

```
        // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

        // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Get iterator to all the rows in current sheet
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = mySheet.iterator();

        // Traversing over each row of XLSX file
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t");
                    break;
                default :

                }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: Ex n thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlbeans/XmlObject at L2t.main(L2t.java:30)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Comment: It looks like an error because of version mismatch in jars. Try using different version of jar for xlsx reading.

Comment: okay dude. but i included poi-3.9.

Comment: @abhilash.r It would be better to add your error message to the question instead of a comment - you have more formatting options there.

Comment: sorry dude ,am new to stackoverflow .i don't know the formatting options.

Comment: Sounds like a BuildPath problem. What IDE are you using? Do you get the same error when you build from the command line using javac?

Comment: Netbeans IDE 8.0.2  not yet .

Comment: In cmd also am receiving error message like org.package.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist .what is the problem guys .

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer . for this,we need to import dom4j jar and poi ooxml schemas also .i forgot about this two files